# Opening a GridView Row in the same window as Parent Page while retaining my values?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I have this VB.NET code for a ASP.NET Gridview :

```
    Protected Sub GridView3_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles GridView3.RowDataBound
    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        e.Row.Cells(1).Attributes("onmouseover") = "this.style.cursor='hand';this.style.textDecoration='underline';"
        e.Row.Cells(1).Attributes("onmouseout") = "this.style.textDecoration='none';"
        Dim Index As Integer = e.Row.RowIndex
        e.Row.Cells(1).Attributes("OnClick") = "window.open('AreaQuery.aspx?AreaID=" + GridView3.DataKeys(e.Row.RowIndex).Value.ToString + "');"
    End If
End Sub
```

The Line of code :

```
e.Row.Cells(1).Attributes("OnClick") = "window.open('AreaQuery.aspx?AreaID=" + GridView3.DataKeys(e.Row.RowIndex).Value.ToString + "');"
```

Opens up the new page ( with the passed values ) in a new window , I need this to be in the same window as the page it's come from ... How do I achieve this & How would it be implemented?

Answer (score 0):

try to use this **'_self'**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 window.open ('YourNewPage.htm','_self',false)
</script>
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp